# How to share database between java program and iOS application?

Tags: java, ios, mysql, database

I have written a reservation program in java language. I am using MySQL database to record usernames and other details. Now the company is asking me to write an iOS application which can access and modify those data in MySQL database. Should I change my database platform? I appreciate if anyone can share information if has experience about this.

Comment: Create a web service through which your ios app can communicate via standard http. If that's to much, take a look at parse.com

Comment: Is the Java application a destop application or is it running as a web servrer?

Comment: it is a desktop application.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I saw parse.com before. Do I need to use REST API?

Comment: @Bernard Parse.com provides a nice library for iOS

Comment: @GoogleHireMe I already worked with parse.com for iOS but I am looking for some tutorial to sync these data to my desktop application in java language.

Comment: @Bernard 
Parse doesn't provide their own Java library, however, you can use third-party java library https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j

Comment: @Bernard or, of course, you can use Rest API, but, as for me, it's less comfortable (:

Comment: @Bernard You can have a look at all third-party libraries for Parse here https://parse.com/docs/api_libraries

Comment: @GoogleHireMe Thanks for your help. What is your suggestion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73733/discussion-between-googlehireme-and-bernard).

Comment: @Bernard Yes and no. There are APIs available for most languages. I've been using it on some ios projects and am pretty happy with how the api works